# Link_to not finding action in controller even though the action is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following View. Basically once you click it, it should generate a new book post. Each book post is associated with a post. But I keep getting this error: `AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'generate_book' could not be found for PostsController):`

```
<%= link_to "New Book", generate_book_post_path(post.id), data: { turbo_method: :post } %>

# above code is within <% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

Here's my posts controller:

```rb
        
    def generate_book
        post = Post.find(params[:id])
        book_output = GetBook.call # calls services

        Book.create(post: post, one: book_output)

        redirect_to books_path
    end
```

My routes:

```rb
  resources :posts do
    post :generate_book, on: :member
  end
```

I've made sure there's no typo. I'd really appreciate help.

Comment: In bash, try `rails routes | grep generate_book`. What comes up?

Comment: @Luke Thank you for your comment. For some reason I get the same route, generate_book_post. I also tried putting controller: :posts, action: :generate_book and I get an error that no route matches those.

Comment: It feels to me like the error is actually not about `link_to` not finding the correct routes in the `routes.rb` and not being able to build the link. But when clicking the link, the routing not being able to find the method in the expected controller. Please double-check that you placed the method in the public section of the `PostsController` that should exist at `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb` (plural is important here). Btw (not related to your issue): Following common Rails idiom, a create book method would be defined a `create` in a `books_controller`

Answer (score 1):

Edit your question with full controller code and `rails routes` output. Try the following steps:

1. Run `rails routes` and check if this route exists with correct request method and controller action specified.
2. Check server logs for request method and path. It should match step #1
3. Make sure to not have any extra `end` in your controller after your action ends.
4. Make sure your action is not declared `private` in your controller.
5. Also, making changes to anything outside of `app/` such as `config/routes.rb` will require a server restart.